How about a tag for logos?
We've had a spat of questions this week that are amazing logo-centric:

Octan
The LEGO Logo Font
my favorite, The Coffee Chain

And it isn't hard to find older questions that might be easier to discover with this tag:

Chicago Blackhawks logo Lego building instructions
Where can I find the LEGO fire dept. logo in high resolution or in vector format
Did LEGO ever make bricks without the LEGO logo?
LEGO and fuel company commercial relationship?

Is this enough related questions to warrant creating a tag?

I guess the question is how related are they really? And what benefit do we get by grouping them as such.
A question about the font used in the LEGO logo is really about branding, or design, rather than the logo specifically, while a question about building a logo doesn't really benefit from being grouped with questions about finding stickers for a particular real or fictional chain.
